# extract data from particular line in html page using php

Tags: php, html, pdf

[this was my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721351/how-to-extract-particular-text-from-pdf-using-php) I was stuck and tried to solve my problem by trying something and got stuck again

I need to extract  name of candidate and his id from a pdf ,so after using pdfparser I extracted the text and downloaded the html page using php

```
<?php
$filename = 'filename.html';
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
header('Content-type: text/html');
// ... the rest of your file
?>
<?php

// Include Composer autoloader if not already done.
include 'C:\Users\amite\Downloads\pdfparser-master (1)\pdfparser-master\vendor\autoload.php';

// Parse pdf file and build necessary objects.
$parser = new  \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('C:\Users\amite\Desktop\Data\001.ApplicationForm-CSE-2015-1-omokop (3).pdf');

$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;


?>
```

I did this cause the info I need that was on line 12 and 13 of the view source page and this was was with all the pdf's I need ,so after downloading the html file I used the code below to see the source page of html file

```
<?php
show_source("filename.html");
?>
```

now when I run the above program I got the source page of html file which I downloaded, now I need to extract data from line 12 and 13 , the output of program looks like this :-

```
<html>
 text
 text
text
text 
text 
text
```

there are no tags except html tag and info I need is on line 12,13, if you need any clarification please ask me I will tell you. 
how should I extract text from line 12,13, if there is another way tell me pls. I am stuck again, if the question is vague I will clarify it or improve it, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the file source into an array with `$source = file('filename.html');` and extract line 12 and 13 via array index 11 and 12 like this `echo $source[11]; //line 12`

Comment: sorry man , I couldn't upvote you because of my lower reputation

Comment: It's ok, not necessary ^^

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
<?php
$str = "1text
 2text
3text
4text 
5text 
6text
7text 
8text 
9text
10text 
11text 
12text
13text
";
$k = array_slice(explode("\n",$str),11,1);
print_r($k);
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/c1vvpq   this is how info on source page i am displaying through the show_source("filename.html"); appears . I need to get text from line 12 and 13